# how to wait to massage to disappear and then reload the page in angular 5

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular (5 ) 
I am using a form and then once the user click the "Save" button the data is saved in the DB and this message pops up

```
msgs: Message[] = [];

this.msgs = [{severity: 'info', summary: 'Confirmed', detail: 'Data was saved'}];
```

i want to clear the data i found this command

```
location.reload();
```

but this also clear the message.
what is the proper way to do it ? maybe put a wait command ? how ? 
or maybe different command not location.reload ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear just the data and left the message after reload, so you should:

1. Using router reload the page (my suggestion with router param to have an identifier that the page reloaded after save)
2. Based on the identifier show/not show the message after page is loaded.

something like this:

```
save() {
    router.navigate(['my-page/', this.isSaved]);
}
```

Then in the same component:

```
ngOnInit() {
if (this.isSaved) {
    this.messageShow = true;
}
```

In the HTML template you should have something like:

```
<div *ngIf="{{this.isSaved}}">
    {{myMsg}}
</div>
```